# Can you use ModelBinding with a GET request?

Tags: c#, get, model-binding

I'm curious if it's possible to bind a query string that is passed in with a `GET` request to a `Model`.

For example, if the `GET` url was `https://localhost:1234/Users/Get?age=30&status=created`

Would it be possible on the `GET` action to bind the query parameters to a `Model` like the following:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<JsonResult> Get(UserFilter filter) 
{
    var age = filter.age;
    var status = filter.status;
}

public class UserFilter
{
    public int age { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}
```

I am currently using `ASP.NET MVC` and I have done quite a bit of searching but the only things I can find are related to `ASP.NET Web API`. They suggest using the `[FromUri]` attribute but that is not available in MVC.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested the this, and it does work (at least in .net core 3.1)

```
[HttpGet("test")]
        public IActionResult TestException([FromQuery]Test test)
        {
            return Ok();
        }

        public class Test
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Yes { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately that is not available in .net 4.6.2

Answer (score 0):

You can can create an ActionFilterAttribute where you will parse the query parameters, and bind them to a model. And then you can decorate your controller method with that attribute.
For example

```
 public class UserFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            var controller = actionContext.ControllerContext.Controller as CustomApiController;
            var queryParams = actionContext.Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs();
            var ageParam = queryParams.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Key == "age");
            var statusParam = queryParams.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Key == "status");

            controller.UserFilter = new UserFilter { 
                                          Age = int.Parse(ageParam.Value),
                                          Status = statusParam.Value
                                          };
        }
}
```

The CustomApiController (inherits from your current controller) and has a UserFilter property so you can keep the value there. You can also add null checks in case some of the query parameters are not sent with the request..

Finally you can decorate your controller method

```
[HttpGet]
[UserFilter]
public async Task<JsonResult> Get() 
{
    var age = UserFilter.age;
    var status = UserFilter.status;
}
```